# Linux - Find if process is ready or running

Tags: c++, linux, process, file-descriptor, proc

I'm developing a C++ application with process monitoring capabilities, which monitors state changes based on this model: http://www.macdesign.net/capella/it4813/images/stallings-Linux_process-thread_states-f4.18.png

However, as /proc/pid/status combines both the "ready" and "executing" states into "running", I'm at a loss as to how I can find out which of these states a process is actually in. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I may discover this?

Comment: Suggestions: look [here](http://procps.sourceforge.net/), [here](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=84) and [here](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=174).  The first link in particular, even though it uses /proc, should give you lots of useful tips.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: On low-end single core machines -e.g. cheap netbooks- only one process is running at a given instant, and that would be your monitoring process (on multicore machines, the story is different). So you actually want to measure if a given process has been running during the last few jiffies, ie. perhaps during the last decisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is malformed.  On a single CPU, it's literally **never** possible to see a process in the "running" state, because by definition the monitoring process has the CPU.  If you really need fine-grained logging control over process transitions, you need to do it in the kernel (or at least with in-kernel support -- see lttng or systemtap for tools that might help here).  Tools for tracking CPU usage from userspace are more coarse-grained, either using the total usage numbers already tracked by the kernel (e.g. `/usr/bin/time`) or by sampling the process table at intervals (bootchart works this way).